# How can I make a upside down map in a right positon in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

**Context**

I am using `terra::rast()` to read a `nc` file and plot it.

But the ploted map is upside down.

When I used `raster::raster()` to read the `nc` file and plot it. The map is right.

**Question**

How can I make the upside down map right when using `terra::rast()` to read the `nc`?

**Reproducible code**

I have uploaded `pm2.5_year_2013.nc`data on my github.
The data can be found at [here](https://github.com/lizhiwei1994/data/blob/main/pm2.5_year_2011.nc)

```
library(terra)
air = rast('pm2.5_year_2013.nc')
plot(air) # an upside down China map

air2 = raster::raster('pm2.5_year_2013.nc')
plot(air2) # an right China map
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this is a quirk of the data rather than than the `terra` package. I didn't try loading it in `raster` though - it does seem strange it would be the other way round in a different package.

In any case you can use `terra::flip()` to make it the right way around.

```r
air2  <- terra::flip(air, direction="vertical")
plot(air2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was fixed in the development version of "terra" (or the version of GDAL that it uses on windows)

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

And now it works as expected.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.30
r <- rast("pm2.5_year_2011.nc")
plot(r)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I'll track down, and believe was fixed in development 1.6.21 I think.